# Animate an item rendered into a Marionette collection view

Tags: javascript, marionette

I've a collection containing models that represent the apps navigation items. In my app the navigation is on the left side of the screen, and I want to be able to slide in the nav items one by one whenever they are rendered. The navigation container is a Collection View, and the nav items are it's Item Views.

In the Collection View I have changed the **appendHtml** method to look like this.

```
    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView, index) {
            console.log('APPENDING ITEM VIEW', itemView.el);
            itemView.assignNewlyCreated();
            collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
            itemView.slideIn();
    },
```

The Item Views have these relevant methods:

```
    // Label the dom element as newly created
    assignNewlyCreated: function () {
        this.$el.addClass('newly-created');
    },

    // Slide in the item.
    slideIn: function () {
        console.log('sliding in element', this.el);
        this.$el.animate({left: 0});
    }
```

Since the **newly-created** class has styles that push the item off the screen to the left, I was thinking that if I append it like this and then slide it in once it's in the DOM, it should work. Unfortunately this is not working, and the nav items already appear on the screen with no animation. Am I doing something wrong here, and does anyone know why this doesn't seem to be working? I am thinking there may be an error in another part of my app, but if that is the case and If that is fixed, should the above code work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this :

```
MyItemView = Backbone.Marionette.extend({
  template: "#template",
  className: "newly-created",
  onRender: function(){
    this.$el.animate({left: 0});
  }
});
```

This sets the class on the item directly, then slides the item view in when it is rendered by the CollectionView (onRender is called automatically fi it is defined, there's nothing else for you to do).

Comment: But Initially when the collection view is rendered it `el` is not attached to dom so he will not see the transition effect.Only when an add event is fired on collection later (i.e after appending the collection view to dom) he can see this transition